# How to get the php session data in javascript function of a .js file

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I want to take the session data in .js file.Here i want the data in a function
Now i'm directly put the value.How to take it from session.

**.js file**

```
  function callAllfnt(){ 
   get_data(1) ;
  }
```

I want the 1 as session data.How to take it

Comment: PHP tag is not allowed in `.js` file. You have to use `ajax` for it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it on page load the try this:

```js
function callAllfnt() {
  var data = "<?php echo $_SESSION['givenName']; ?>";
}
```

In later part in the life cycle of the application, use `AJAX`

Comment: It's not error to use single quotes here. because you're in php and outside quote is just text.

Comment: @jcubic, I guessed so but was not sure ;) Inner statement will be parsed first(`pre-processed`) and will be wrapped by outer quotes, am I right ?

Answer (score 2):

1)

**View File**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Sessionvalue = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('session_name')";
<script>
```

After load your js file

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**JS FILE**

```
function callAllfnt() {
  var data = SessionValue;
}
```

(OR)

2) Using Ajax call and Get the Session value

Answer (score 1):

You need to create php script that will return Session data and call that with ajax like this:

php

```
if (isset($_GET['var'])) {
   echo json_encode($_SESSION[$_GET['var']]);
}
```

js with jQuery:

```
function get_data(variable, callback) {
    $.get('session.php', {'var':variable}, function(data) {
       callback(data);
    }, 'json');
}
```

and you can call that function using:

```
get_data(1, function(value) {
   alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

just use php tag with in single quotes if you java script is written in html page like

```
function callAllfnt() {
    var value = '<?php echo $_SESSION["varName"]; ?>';
    get_data(value) ;
}
```

But if your javascript code is written seperate js file then use ajax.

Third option is if your javascript file included in php file then create a javascript variable on top of js file including code and use that variable in js file.